# How to get the value of field with the same name in multiple forms?

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a web application in which the same HTML form is generated/loaded dynamically using AJAX.

Here is the sample form (almost 20 forms are loaded at a time):

```
<div class="replybox" id="rbox1">
    <cite>
        <form action="" method="post" id="replypostform">       
            <p>
                <textarea id="replytxt" name="replytxt" rows="2" cols="43" class="replytextarea"></textarea>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Reply"/>
            </p>    
        </form>
    </cite>
</div>
```

And I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate them. The form validation works fine but now I just need to take the content of `textarea` upon submit, if I simply use `.val()` function then it will only return the first forms' `textarea` content.

But I want the content of the `textarea` on which user clicked.

Here is my jquery validation code:

```
jQuery("#replypostform").live('mouseover', function(){
    jQuery(this).validate({
        errorElement:'div',
            rules: {
                replytxt:{
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                replytxt:{
                    required: "<div style='color:red'>Please write a reply for posting it.</div>"
                }
            },
            submitHandler:function(mform){

            //here I want get the content of textarea
        }
    });
});
```

Here I just did a trick with mouseover event to validate the multiple form with same name/id and same fields.

My page loads around 20 exact same form using AJAX.

So suggest me how can I get the content of `textarea` of a particular form.

-Thanks

Comment: An ID should show up only once in an HTML document. If you're using this form multiple times you should use classes for identification instead of IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and it works

i know it's not a correct way but this trick did the work

here is my jQuery code:

```
textBoxVal="";
        jQuery("#replytxt").live('keyup',function(){
        textBoxVal=jQuery(this).val();

        });
```

then in submitHandler()

i used "textBoxVal" values.

Comment: the code written above in the solution provided by me is going to be outside of the jQuery("#replypostform").live('mouseover', function(){
} then in submithandler() just take the value as given above

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//here I want get the content of textarea
var textareaValue = $("#replytxt", this).val();
```

The `this` supplies the context of the `form` which fired the `mouseover` event to look for the `#replytxt` in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#replypostform").find("#replytxt").val();
```

also stop the event from bubbling

```
jQuery("#replypostform").live('mouseover',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
```

and get the content of text area like

```
$(this).find("#replytxt").text();
```

Comment: i tried this but it gives me "undefined" value,but thanks for the reply

Comment: you mean if you do `console.log($("#replypostform").find("#replytxt").val())` you get undefined in the firebug console...

Answer (score -2):

Try [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to match specific element:

as in:

```
$('textarea').eq(0).val()
```

Edit: another example for selectors:

First form's textarea:

```
$('form:eq(0) textarea').val();
```

Second form's 3rd textarea:

```
$('form:eq(1) textarea:eq(2)').val();
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting the OP repeats this 20 times for all his forms? What if the requirements change and he needs 100 forms? Or if they decide to let users dynamically add forms?

Comment: you are not getting the point the hovered form's text area's value is required ...

Comment: thanks for the effort but i am sorry i can't specify for every elements upto 20